# Flex Panel children aren't created when a custom component uses Panel as base

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I found some behavior in FLex that I'm not familiar with and can't figure out WHY it's happening. Can anyone explain? I have a CustomComponent whose base component is a Spark Panel. Here is an example:

```
<s:Panel title="hello world panel">
    <s:Label text="hello world" />
    <s:controlBarContent>
        <s:Button label="hello world button" />
    </s:controlBarContent>
</s:Panel>
```

In another class I use the new operator to create a new CustomComponent and add it to an mx Canvas that is already on the stage. When this happens, the CustomComponent shows up, I can see the the title bar and the title, I can see the button in the controlBarContent, but I can't see the content (the Label).

If I take the code from my custom component (the Panel portion) and just put it directly in the Canvas that I was adding it to then it works just fine!

Also, if I make my CustomComponent have a base of Canvas and then put my panel in there it also works just fine!

```
<mx:Canvas>
    <s:Panel title="hello world panel">
        <s:Label text="hello world" />
        <s:controlBarContent>
            <s:Button label="hello world button" />
        </s:controlBarContent>
    </s:Panel>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Is this a possible bug in flex? Or is this the way it is supposed to work and if it is supposed to work this way can anyone enlighten me to as why?

Thanks!

Comment: From what you described, it works fine for me. Can you share the code of creating and adding your custom panel? I also recommend you to use s:Group component instead of mx:Canvas which is kind of outdated.

Comment: I have also tried Group instead of Canvas, I only used Canvas since I'm modifying other people's code and that is their standard. As for the code to create the panel I just use new CustomComponent() and then use addElement to add it to its parent.